# SMLNJ, Try to run a program from a file, unknown error

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I was trying to execute a few lines of code from a file using 'use' command but I'm getting error which I don't understand,

```
StdIn:1.6-1.10 Error unclosed string
```

[Screen Shot](http://s29.postimg.org/k7errcag7/Screenshot_2014_02_11_17_22_26.png)

I search everywhere, trying to find what does that error mean but now luck,

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Unclosed string" means that you've started a string using `"`, but you did not close it using another `"`.

So why do you get that error in your case - clearly you do have the proper amount of `"`s there? Well, if we look at the column numbers, we see that the error complains about the section starting at the first `"` and ending at the h after the backslash, meaning it expected the string to end there.

So basically what the error message is telling you is that it is not expecting an h there. Why not? Because it was preceded by a backslash, backslashes in strings start escape sequences and `\h` is not a valid escape sequence. So you need to replace your backslashes with double backslashes (or single forward slashes) to escape them and that should fix the problem.